# Git config did not change username

Tags: git, bash, http

So, I changed my git username to something different a while back. Now, I am attempting to change it back. I used the following command with Git Bash:

```
git config --global user.name "PreviousUserName"
```

I was unable to change the username, which became apparent after using this command since my current username showed up, as if the previous command was ignored:

```
git config user.name
"CurrentUserName"
```

I find it strange that Git Bash did not ask for a password upon changing my credentials, since I am using HTTP and not an SSH key on my laptop. Does anyone know what the issue could be? HTTP works fine for my purposes, so if someone has a solution with HTTP, that would be preferred.

Comment: Why are you using `--global` for the write command, but not for the read command?

Comment: It's also worth noting here that Git's idea of `user.name` and `user.email` are quite independent of any https or ssh authentication. (That is, when Git makes a commit, it just trusts your configuration. When your browser or ssh agents make connections and provide identification, they do so in a more-secure manner, without quite so much trust, and don't use the information Git is using / providing.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I speculate that the username was set for the particular repo in question, and that this previous setting is overriding the global setting you made.  If so, then navigate to this repo and try the following:

```
git config user.name "PreviousUserName"
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem. Going to repo folder and manually adding

```
[user]
    name=""PreviousUserName"
```

to .git/config worked fine.